# Duplicate entries for index in pandas pivot function

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot, pandas

I'm trying to create a new dataframe that derives from pivoting this one:

```
                 dataframe name      date tenor mat strike      capvol
      0   EUR CapFloor Volat_3m  20120903    3m  1y   0.25  152.202160
      1   EUR CapFloor Volat_3m  20120903    3m  1y   0.50  151.969370
      2   EUR CapFloor Volat_3m  20120903    3m  1y      1  149.266970
      3   EUR CapFloor Volat_3m  20120903    3m  1y   1.50  152.940750
      4   EUR CapFloor Volat_3m  20120903    3m  1y      2  157.229350
      5   EUR CapFloor Volat_3m  20120903    3m  1y   2.25  159.325890
```

My goal is to have data grouped by date, mat and strike (I can drop the '3m' and 'dataframe name' columns since they're common to all data).
I tried with the command:

```
      df = frame.pivot('date','mat','strike')
```

but get this error:

```
      'Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'
```

altough I checked with my data and contains no duplpicates on rows.

Can anyone help me with this issue, or propose an alternative approach to the pivot function?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `set_index` is what you want? `pivot` is a reshape operation:

```
In [4]: frame.set_index(['date', 'mat', 'strike'])
Out[4]: 
                            dataframe name tenor     capvol
date     mat strike                                        
20120903 1y  0.25    EUR CapFloor Volat_3m    3m  152.20216
             0.50    EUR CapFloor Volat_3m    3m  151.96937
             1.00    EUR CapFloor Volat_3m    3m  149.26697
             1.50    EUR CapFloor Volat_3m    3m  152.94075
             2.00    EUR CapFloor Volat_3m    3m  157.22935
             2.25    EUR CapFloor Volat_3m    3m  159.32589


In [7]: df.capvol.unstack('mat')
Out[7]: 
mat                     1y
date     strike           
20120903 0.25    152.20216
         0.50    151.96937
         1.00    149.26697
         1.50    152.94075
         2.00    157.22935
         2.25    159.32589
```